# How are CPython extensions able to call functions defined inside CPython?

Tags: python, c, dll, cpython

In the [documentation for writing CPython extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html), one can find the following code:

```
static PyObject *
spam_system(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *command;
    int sts;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;
    sts = system(command);
    return PyLong_FromLong(sts);
}
```

As we can see, this function in the external C extension is able to use a function defined (I think) inside the main CPython interpreter source code: `PyArg_ParseTuple`.

If we were to simply build the extension source file directly (aka `gcc -shared myextension.c`, etc.), even while including the necessary header `<Python.h>`, the linker would complain about `undefined reference to PyArg_ParseTupe`.

So how are CPython extensions built, in a way that allows them to freely reference functions from the CPython code base?

Are extensions built together with the source code of the actual interpreter? Are they linked with the object files of the actual interpreter? A different approach?

Please refer to approach relevant to Windows. Additional information about Linux is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Linux the relevant library call is [`dlopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), where "dl" stands for Dynamic Linking. The [manual page says](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen):

> If the executable was linked with the flag "`-rdynamic`" (or, synonymously, "`--export-dynamic`"), then the global symbols in the executable will also be used to resolve references in a dynamically loaded library.

In other words, references from inside the dynamic loaded library are resolved at load time by the dynamic linker.

Comment: In my case I fail at the compilation point, before running the host executable, because the linker complains about `undefined reference`s. Any idea?